# Use of "ci" in this sentence

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, pronouns, sentences, particles

Could you explain the use of **ci** in the following sentence?

> La più famosa è quella del 3 maggio 1915 dove dice di voler interrompere la terapia psicanalitica perché non **ci** crede e secondo lui ormai non può più guarire.

It seems to me that the sense is: ... because he doesn't believe in it ... where it refers to *la terapia psicanalitica*. Why is it not *perché non gli crede* or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases "ci" is used to replace "a/in/su/con questo/questa/queste", in this specific case "ci" replaces:

> perché non crede **a questa terapia**

You need to use "gli" or "le" with people, for example:

> Marco è un bugiardo, non **gli** credo.

> Marta è una bugiarda, non **le** credo.